# How can I Enlarge the error window in pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

[image]So my problem is that the error window in pgAdmin is small.

Although I managed to extended it I can't view everything written because the error page refers to the problem itself in the last line which I can't view.

I really don't know what to do. I've been trying to find a solution for hours.
Any answer would be much appreciated.

**Edit**: **I actually solved it** with File->RunTime->Zoom out(multiple times) so then the window could show everything because the letters were smaller. I wish I had seen this option earlier! [image]

Comment: Have you tried File>Lock layout>None

Comment: This option is already chosen. The problem is that the window covers the entire screen and there is not a side bar so I can't scroll down.